Centering a \parbox around an existing code
I have this code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Define the student box (1 digit box)
\newcommand{\studentbox}{
    \colorbox{gray!20}{%
        \makebox[34em][c]{%
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{0} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{1} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{2} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{3} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{4} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{5} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{6} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{7} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{8} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{9} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
        }%
    }
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black,  line width=2mm, , inner sep=1em, align=center] (box) {
        % Use a parbox or minipage to allow line breaks
        \parbox{36em}{ % Set the width of the box for proper line break
            % Counter definitions
            \newcount\digit
            \newcount\maxdigit
            \digit=0
            \maxdigit=9  
            \noindent \\
            \loop
                \noindent\studentbox 
                \advance\digit by 1
                \ifnum\digit<\maxdigit
            \repeat
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}

that produces

I would like it to be more centered.
That is : the spacings represented by the blue arrows should be identical;  the spacings represented by the red arrows should be identical.
Thanks
Using :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% Define the student box (one digit box)
\newcommand{\studentbox}{\hfill
    \hbox to \textwidth{% Ensure it spans the full line or fits content
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{0} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{1} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{2} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{3} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{4} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{5} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{6} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{7} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{8} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}
            \makebox[3em][c]{\texttt{9} \textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}}  
}
}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=gray!20,
    colframe=black, 
    width=36em, 
    height=12em, 
    halign=center, 
    valign=center, 
    sharp corners, 
    boxrule=1mm, 
]
    % Use a loop to generate multiple student boxes
    \foreach \i in {1,...,9}{ % Adjust the range as needed
        \studentbox \\ % Add spacing between boxes
    }
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}

Makes something nicer indeed.


Welcome to TeX.SX! If you just want to draw a box, you should look at the tcolorbox package, instead of using a node in a tikzpicture.

indeed. Much easier !

I am interested; did you create a tcolorbox-solution?

Yes it is in the post. But I am not sure it is perfectly centered

Could you remove the solution from the question and move it to an answer (you can answer your own question)?

It is not really an answer cause I am not sure it works perfectly

Aha. So I mean a real tcolorbox solution or a real TikZ solution would no longer have to contain anything like makebox. Both packages contain home remedies that can achieve what you want.

For a tcolorbox-solution you should not need pure LaTeX tools like makebox, parbox etc.
The tcolorbox package usually contains all the keys that can be used to set what you need.
Since you want a frame around the raster-arrangement, you do not need tcbraster, but tcboxedraster:

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% test
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Cols{10}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Rows{9}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\BoxNoMax{\Rows*\Cols-1}% Number of last box
\begin{tcboxedraster}[% raster options ============
raster columns=\Cols, raster rows=\Rows, 
raster equal height, 
raster column skip=0pt, raster row skip=0pt,
raster every box/.style={
boxrule=0pt, frame hidden, sharp corners, 
fontupper=\ttfamily,
valign=center, halign=center, 
boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0.25ex, bottom=0.25ex, 
colback=lightgray,  
% ===========================
}]{% box options ==================
width=36em, % complete width 
colback=lightgray,  
boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, bottom=0.5ex, top=0.5ex, 
boxrule=1mm, colframe=black, sharp corners, 
}% ===========================
\foreach[evaluate={\B=int(mod(\b,10))}] \b in {0,...,\BoxNoMax}{%%
\begin{tcolorbox}
\B~\textcolor{white}{\rule{1em}{1em}}
\end{tcolorbox}}%%
\end{tcboxedraster}
\end{document}

